# Number of zeros in cosine for one period

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Stupid I know, but for $ \cos(kx+\phi) $ is the number of zeros in the *first*  period always two? Just unsure of myself.

Comment: the number of zero crossing for **any** period is always two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to "prove" it that it is $2$. Assume $k, \phi > 0$, simply solve the equation: $\cos(kx+\phi) = 0\iff kx + \phi = \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\iff x = \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi - 2\phi}{2k} \in \left[0, \dfrac{2\pi}{k}\right]\iff n = 0,1.$
This means there are $2$ zeros in the first period.

Comment: What about n=2 does that not work?

Comment: $n = 2$ results in a contradiction so it doesn' work.

Comment: Why the contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

For any sine/cosine function, the number of zero crossings will always be two. If you managed to understand that for any period but the *first* one, just notice that all the periods are strictly the same, that's why they're called periods ;)

Btw, for a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, what would *first* mean ?